# Move object in the same direction

Tags: transforms

I have a problem with movement. I would like to move all the objects in the same way.
In the original file the movement is correct in this file the movement is strange.
How can I solve it?

I have upload the file.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've switched the *Transform Orientations* to *Local*, which means that the objects will move along their local axis. For some of them these axis are not aligned with the global axis, so you either need to switch to *Global*, or apply the rotation of these objects:

[image]